How to do pagination in Hapi FHIR when using Consent Interceptor
My Project recently started using HAPI-FHIR-JPAStarter, and it has consent Interceptor which is written by external team and even the Fhir server is in JAVA. (My background is .Net using calling this FHIR in my .net web API).
Basically we have consent resource, where actor = practitioner/{id} and subject = patient/id. Provision.Date array contains the all the list of diagnostic report that doctor can see for that patient.
this is the query we are using to get that all the diagnostic reports that doctor can view
/DiagnosticReport?_include=DiagnosticReport%3Asubject&_include=DiagnosticReport%3Abased-on&_sort=-issued&results-interpreter=Practitioner/{id}&status%3Anot=cancelled&_offset=0&_count=10

My understanding on pagination is that, _offset is the number of resources that FHIR should skip and _count is the number of resources that FHIR should get. So to get page 2, I would do _offSet=10&_count=10.
and now my issue is doctor is assgined on 1000 Diagnostic recourses and he has access to 300 diagnostic report and when I paginated the page one with count 10, let say in 10 Diagnostic reports doctor can view two then only two are return in the above query(where the two diagnostic report reference are present in Consent) and some 4 diagnostic reports data in page 2 etc.
This leads to inconsistency of showing results in all the pages in UI.
Is there a way that I can get 10 Diagnostic reports on each page.
Please be so kind and ask me question so I can fill with the info that I can now,
I am new to FHIR server which is in JAVA.
Thank you in advance for help.
